# The date of yesterday in flutter

Tags: date, flutter, dart

How can I calculate **yesterdays date** in dart/flutter?
I have the date of today:

```
DateTime.now()
```

But I **can't just do -1**.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days:1))
```

More info at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html